# Setting array associative value to 1-6 dynamically

Tags: php

I have the following array `$args:

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 100,
    'post_type' => array('product', 'product_variation'),
    'product_cat' => 'Caravans', 
    'tax_query' => array(                   
                        array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'pa_berth',                
                            'field' => 'name',                    
                            'terms' => array( $berth ),    
                            'include_children' => true,           
                            'operator' => 'IN'                    
                        )
                    ),
                 );
```

I'm setting the `$berth` value from POST. However $berth is not always set from post, but the `'terms'` key always expects a value (and in this case it needs to be 1,2,3,4,5,6). I'm trying to deal with that with the following condition.

```
if(isset($_POST['berth'])) {
    $berth = (int)$_POST['berth'];
}
else {
    $berth = 1,2,3,4,5,6;
}
```

So if 'berth' is not set on post, I'm trying to pass in those integers. However this is not valid PHP. What is the best solution here?

Comment: `$berth = array(1,2,3,4,5,6);`

Comment: `$berth=range(1,6);`

Comment: I would be interested to know how `berth` is defined in your HTML as if it is a simple scalar text field containing `1,2,3,4` then `$berth = (int)$_POST['berth'];` will also not do what you expect either

Answer (score 2):

You are expecting `$berth` to be array.

If not set from `$_POST`, you need to set a default value.

Following code addresses both the issues:

```
if (isset($_POST['berth'])) {
 $berth = (int)$_POST['berth'];
 $berth = array($berth);
}
else {
 $berth = array(1,2,3,4,5,6);
}
```

Also, change latest part to (pass `$berth` directly as array instead of creating a new array with `$berth` as first element.

```
...
array(
 'taxonomy' => 'pa_berth',                
  'field' => 'name',                    
  'terms' => $berth,    
  'include_children' => true,           
  'operator' => 'IN'                    
 )
...
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to complicate this, you can just do the following:

```
if(isset($_POST['berth'])) {
    $berth = array( (int) $_POST['berth'] );
}
else {
    $berth = array( 1,2,3,4,5,6 );
}
```

This way you are always ensuring the $berth variable is an array and then you can pass the array itself to the terms field, like so:

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 100,
    'post_type' => array('product', 'product_variation'),
    'product_cat' => 'Caravans', 
    'tax_query' => array(                   
                        array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'pa_berth',                
                            'field' => 'name',                    
                            'terms' => $berth,    
                            'include_children' => true,           
                            'operator' => 'IN'                    
                        )
                    ),
                 );
```

Comment: Now it is, it was not originally

Comment: I have now added in the necessary clarifications on what was changed in the code and why...